# Format SVN Log Output

Tags: bash, svn

I would like to fetch the log message for a file committed to svn.
I'm using the following command currently:

```
 svn --non-interactive log "myfile.c" | sed -e "s/[\-]//g"'
```

The output is :

```
r42153 | sam | 2012-03-02 14:51:53 -0800 (Fri, 02 Mar 2012) | 1 line

Update to code.
```

I would like to get rid of the first line "r42153 | sam |...." and output just the log message.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `| grep -v "what you don't want to include"` to leave out the lines you don't want. However, trying to leave out anything with a `\n` just leaves out everything, so don't do that.

Comment: Thanks @Dez. I forgot about grep. I ended up using                      grep -v  "| [0-9]\+ line[s]\?$"

Answer (score 2):

You can throw away useful lines from your commit messages while using grep.
SVN provides propget command out of the box:

use

```
$ svn propget svn:log --revprop -r R [TARGET]
```

to get commit message

or

```
$ svn propget svn:log --revprop -r R [TARGET] --xml
```

to get it in XML.

TARGET is path to repository and can be omitted id you are in working copy.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `| sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/-\+\(\n[^\n]*\n\)\?//g'` to remove all "---" with treir next lines.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are logging a single revision, you can use

```
svn log -rXXXX | tail -n+4 | head -n-1
```

to get rid of everything except the message.